# Notification settings always being the same

Tags: python, if-statement, discord, notifications, discord.py

No matter the notification settings, `tip` will always be equal to `NotificationLevel.only_mentions`. If you print `notifications` before the *if* statement however, it will print the correct notification settings. How can I fix it?

```python
@bot.command()
async def notifications(ctx):
  notifications = ctx.guild.default_notifications

  if notifications == "NotificationLevel.only_mentions":
    tip = "Tip: message1"

  else:
    tip = "Tip: message2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
ctx.guild.default_notifications.name == "WhatYouWantToCompare"
```

Should be what you are looking for. You can't compare an `Enum` the way you are trying to do this.

**Adapted to your case, it would be:**

```py
if notifications.name == "only_mentions":
```

Comment: huh? both `notifications` and `NotificationLevel.only_mentions` is a string. (Does not work btw.)

Comment: @Bella The way you try to compare this simply does not work. Check the `name` instead

Comment: Tried what you suggested, still doesn't work. What do you mean by "I can't compare an integer the way Im trying to do it"? Im not comparing any integers, they are all strings...

Comment: @Bella Check the edit I just made and just compare `only_mentions` and `all_messages`. This should do the trick.

Comment: Okay, but what do you mean by "I can't compare an integer the way Im trying to do it"? Im not comparing any integers, they are all strings...

Comment: @Bella `guild.default_notifications.` does not return a `str` at all but rather an `Enum`. So my `int` guess was also wrong, I will correct it

Comment: oh alright, thank you! I always try to understand the issue in my problems so sorry if I wasted your time!

Comment: @Bella No worries, happy coding! :D